# upgrade schedule from trust.salesforce.com

Tags: api, trust

Is there anyway to get the upgrade schedule from https://api.status.salesforce.com/v1/docs/ aka the Trust API?

What I'd like to do is for a given instance find out this info that they list on their calendar: https://status.salesforce.com/status

[image: EU5 on June 02]

I like to query for EU5 and get the answer: 2017-06-02 20:00:00EST

Is that possible?

Comment: Did you try the maintenances api mentioned in the docs with current or future datetime ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you can query the `/maintenances` path to get this information.

[image: Explore Maintenances]

> **Curl**
>
> ```
> curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: JWT EU5' 'https://api.status.salesforce.com/v1/maintenances?service=coreService&instance=EU5'
> ```
>
> **Request URL**
>
> ```
> https://api.status.salesforce.com/v1/maintenances?service=coreService&instance=EU5
> ```
>
> **Request Headers**
>
> ```
> {
>     "Accept": "application/json"
> }
> ```
>
> Response Body
>
> ```
> [
>   {
>     "id": 1505,
>     "message": {
>       "maintenanceType": "scheduledMaintenance",
>       "availability": "availabilityLiveAgentNotAvailable",
>       "eventStatus": "confirmed"
>     },
>     "externalId": "a3GB00000004nAlMAI",
>     "name": "Live Agent Summer ‘17 Release Preparation Maintenance",
>     "plannedStartTime": "2017-05-21T02:00:00.000Z",
>     "plannedEndTime": "2017-05-21T02:10:00.000Z",
>     "additionalInformation": null,
>     "MaintenanceEvents": [],
>     "updatedAt": "2017-05-10T19:33:23.404Z",
>     "isCore": true,
>     "affectsAll": true,
>     "MaintenanceImpacts": [],
>     "instanceKeys": [
>       "EU5"
>     ],
>     "serviceKeys": [
>       "coreService"
>     ]
>   },
>   {
>     "id": 1819,
>     "message": {
>       "maintenanceType": "release",
>       "availability": "unavailable",
>       "eventStatus": "confirmed"
>     },
>     "externalId": "a3GB00000004lDkMAI",
>     "name": "Spring '18 Major Release",
>     "plannedStartTime": "2018-02-10T01:00:00.000Z",
>     "plannedEndTime": "2018-02-10T01:05:00.000Z",
>     "additionalInformation": null,
>     "MaintenanceEvents": [],
>     "updatedAt": "2017-05-10T19:19:31.348Z",
>     "isCore": true,
>     "affectsAll": true,
>     "MaintenanceImpacts": [],
>     "instanceKeys": [
>       "EU5"
>     ],
>     "serviceKeys": [
>       "coreService"
>     ]
>   },
>   {
>     "id": 1565,
>     "message": {
>       "maintenanceType": "release",
>       "availability": "unavailable",
>       "eventStatus": "confirmed"
>     },
>     "externalId": "a3GB00000004X0eMAE",
>     "name": "Summer '17 Major Release",
>     "plannedStartTime": "2017-06-03T00:00:00.000Z",
>     "plannedEndTime": "2017-06-03T00:05:00.000Z",
>     "additionalInformation": null,
>     "MaintenanceEvents": [],
>     "updatedAt": "2017-05-10T19:18:36.694Z",
>     "isCore": true,
>     "affectsAll": true,
>     "MaintenanceImpacts": [],
>     "instanceKeys": [
>       "EU5"
>     ],
>     "serviceKeys": [
>       "coreService"
>     ]
>   },
>   {
>     "id": 1693,
>     "message": {
>       "maintenanceType": "release",
>       "availability": "unavailable",
>       "eventStatus": "confirmed"
>     },
>     "externalId": "a3GB00000004eXyMAI",
>     "name": "Winter '18 Major Release",
>     "plannedStartTime": "2017-10-07T00:00:00.000Z",
>     "plannedEndTime": "2017-10-07T00:05:00.000Z",
>     "additionalInformation": null,
>     "MaintenanceEvents": [],
>     "updatedAt": "2017-05-10T19:19:04.006Z",
>     "isCore": true,
>     "affectsAll": true,
>     "MaintenanceImpacts": [],
>     "instanceKeys": [
>       "EU5"
>     ],
>     "serviceKeys": [
>       "coreService"
>     ]
>   }
> ]
> ```

Specifically, note this element:

```
{
    "id": 1565,
    "message": {
      "maintenanceType": "release",
      "availability": "unavailable",
      "eventStatus": "confirmed"
    },
    "externalId": "a3GB00000004X0eMAE",
    "name": "Summer '17 Major Release",
    "plannedStartTime": "2017-06-03T00:00:00.000Z",
    "plannedEndTime": "2017-06-03T00:05:00.000Z",
    "additionalInformation": null,
    "MaintenanceEvents": [],
    "updatedAt": "2017-05-10T19:18:36.694Z",
    "isCore": true,
    "affectsAll": true,
    "MaintenanceImpacts": [],
    "instanceKeys": [
      "EU5"
    ],
    "serviceKeys": [
      "coreService"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Querying in the future also does it. I assumed that such a major thing would obviously be in the default results.